# Swift: Nested enum with switch statement

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement, enumeration

How can I handle nested enum using switch-case?

I've the following enum:

```
enum Parent: Int {

    enum Nested1: Int {
        case Bow
        case Sword
        case Lance
        case Dagger
    }
    enum Nested2: Int {
        case Wooden
        case Iron
        case Diamond
    }

    //case Nested1  -- Not allowed
    //case Nested2  -- Not allowed
    case Case3
    case Case4
    case Case5

}
```

How can I handle it with `switch-case`?

I've two integer variables for both parent and nested enum cases.

```
let parent = 1
let nested = 2
```

I'm trying in following ways but failed (code below, is not working).

```
let parentCase =  Parent(rawValue: parent)

switch parentCase {
case .Nested1:
    print("Weapon")

case .Nested2:
    print("Helmet")
    let nestedCase = Parent.Nested2(rawValue: nested)

    switch nestedCase {
    case .Wooden:
        print("Weapon")

    case .Iron:
        print("Iron")

    case .Diamond:
        print("Diamond")

    default:
        print("")
    }

default:
    print("")
}
```

Simple question: I want to reach to case `Iron` (or any specific case) with the help of values of `parent` and `nested` integers.

Or Is there any better way to define nested enum, which can be easily handled with switch-case?

Comment: What is the model you are trying to represent?

Comment: Please give the enums and cases better names.

Comment: Business requirement is: I'm getting two integer values as web service response, and I need to identify, what those value represents from these categories and sub categories. I though enum would better but unable to handle it with switch.

Comment: I **hate** this argument, your enum case name is not confidential. `Nested1` is a `Tool`, `Nested2` is a `Material` and `Parent` is something like `Item`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach will work, you just have a few issues with your implementation.  Whether or not this approach is the best way is a different issue which would depend on your requirements.  I would switch to an enum with associated values for the parent if possible.

1. Your `Nested1` enum case can't have the same name as your `Nested1` enum.  Enum cases should start with a lowercase letter anyway so this is easy to fix.
2. Cases for an enum with an `Int` raw value start at 0 by default but you want your first case to map to 1, so you need to explicitly state that.
3. Initializing an enum with a raw value returns an optional, so you should unwrap that optional before switching on it.

Fixing these issues should give you this, which prints "Helmet" and "Iron":

```
enum Parent: Int {

    enum Nested1: Int {
        case bow = 1
        case sword
        case lance
        case dagger
    }

    enum Nested2: Int {
        case wooden = 1
        case iron
        case diamond
    }

    case nested1 = 1
    case nested2
    case case3
    case case4
    case case5

}

let parent = 2
let nested = 2

guard let parentCase = Parent(rawValue: parent) else {
    // Do something to handle invalid enum case here
    fatalError()
}

switch parentCase {
case .nested1:
    print("Weapon")

case .nested2:
    print("Helmet")
    guard let nestedCase = Parent.Nested2(rawValue: nested) else {
        // Do something to handle invalid enum case here
        break
    }

    switch nestedCase {
    case .wooden:
        print("Weapon")

    case .iron:
        print("Iron")

    case .diamond:
        print("Diamond")

    default:
        print("")
    }

default:
    print("")
}
```

Comment: This only seems to work if you know the value of `nested` beforehand, and as such isn't functional as a generic switch formulation. Can you adjust it to be truly functional?